# Multi-Line Dictionary to Single-Line Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

How would you go about converting a multi-line dictionary into one dictionary?

For example, the current dictionary, if printed to the screen, is of the form:

```
{'keyword':'value'}
{'keyword':'value'}
{'keyword':'value'}
{'keyword':'value'}
```

...and so on for over 100 hundred lines. How do you convert this to the following form:

```
{'keyword':'value','keyword':'value','keyword':'value','keyword':'value'}
```

Comment: Are you using `'keyword'` as a placeholder, or are you literally trying to combine four dicts with the same contents?

Comment: That isnt a multi line dictionary. Thats 4 seperate dictionaries on 4 seperate lines. Do you mean a list of dictionaries to a singel dictionary?>

Comment: No 'keyword' is just a placeholder. All the keywords are different (all the values are the same).

Comment: @Luke.py yes well how could you convert the 4 separate dictionaries into ONE dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are asking for multiple dictionaries **(not multiple line dictionary)** to one dictionary.

```
a = {1: 1, 2:2}
b = {2:2, 3:3}
c = {2:3}
{**a, **b, **c}

Out: {1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your initial data is actually a list of dictionaries and your keys are unique accross all your dictionaries I would use something like -

```
example = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]

objOut = {}
for d in example:
    for k,v in d.iteritems():
        objOut[k] = v
```

OR

```
objIn = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3}]

objOut = {}
for d in objIn:
    objOut.update(d)


print objOut
```

Comment: The first code snippet is not Python 3-compatible. Also, why not `objOut[k] = v`, *especially* if the keys are unique? What is the purpose of `setdefault` here?

Comment: yep good point - edited

Answer (score 0):

Given

```
dicts = [{'a':1}, {'b':2}, {'c':3, 'd':4}]
```

Do

```
{k:v for d in dicts for (k, v) in d.items()}
```

or

```
from itertools import chain
dict(chain(*map(dict.items, dicts)))
```

resulting in

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3, 'd': 4}
```